# iphone project - copy and rename in xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, copy, project, rename, xcode4.3

I have an iphone project that is a "base" project. I want to copy this project, rename it and change a couple of files so as to create the final version of each application I want. How can I copy and rename a project in xcode 4.3+ without having any issues (like lost targets or so) ?

Comment: You can rename through refractor. Please refer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851375/cant-rename-files-in-xcode-4-anymore  and  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on your Project, [image]
enter name of your project and prees enter,

it will ask,

**Rename Project Content Items ?**

say *Rename* then it will ask you for *snapshot*, click on `Enable`
and then press `OK`

**Done !**

Answer (score 0):

You could also just create a new project and import only the header and code files you need.